# Trigger VBA code when Worksheet_Activate event occurs - doesn't work if multiple views are active

Tags: excel, vba

I want to suspend calculations when a certain worksheet is activated and then reset calculation to whatever it was originally set to when the sheet is deactivated.

It works if I have one view open.

If I have two (or more) windows open in the same workbook (View/New Window), the Worksheet_Activate and Worksheet_Deactivate events do not trigger when you move between views, so calculations remain set to manual when the user moves to the alternate view.

I did notice the Workbook_WindowActivate and Workbook_WindowDeactivate events, but can't make that work either.

The code below is in the worksheet module.
I need a "Worksheet_GotFocus" event, or for the Worksheet_Activate event to trigger when the View is activated.
Or perhaps I can hang the code off the Selection_Change event so that as soon as the user clicks within the sheet in question, it triggers the code, but not sure how to handle the deactivation in that case.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim vCalc As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'save auto calc setting - suspend auto calcs
    vCalc = Application.Calculation
    If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then _ 
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    'force calculation of UDF's (leave related)
    If Range("rfRLeaveChanged") = "X" Then
        'blah blah blah
    End If
    'reset auto calc (if applicable)
    If Application.Calculation <> vCalc Then _
        Application.Calculation = vCalc

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

OK,I figured it out.  I have to trigger the code in both the sheet and the ThisWorkbook modules.  In ThisWorkbook I trigger it on the Workbook_WindowActivate event.  If Windows.Count > 1 and the active sheet is the sheet in question, I change calculations to manual, or for any other sheet I reset calculations to the users previous setting.